# Convert tensor list into numpy then sum the numbers

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I would like to convert the tensor list into a numpy array/list then sum it and multiply by the number of epochs. I have tried to use MSE_for_all_epochs = sum(np.MSE_for_all_epochs) but getting the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train3_Eval.py", line 177, in 
MSE_for_all_epochs = sum(np.MSE_for_all_epochs)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MSE_for_all_epochs'

```
        mean_test_error = mean_test_error.detach() / len(loader_test)
        #store_MAE += mean_test_error
        MAE_for_all_epochs.append(mean_test_error)

        mse = math.sqrt(loss / len(loader_test))
        #store_MSE +=mse
        MSE_for_all_epochs.append(mse)

        print("Test count error: %f" % mean_test_error)
        print("MSE: %f" % mse)

MSE_for_all_epochs = sum(np.MSE_for_all_epochs)
MAE_for_all_epochs = sum(np.MAE_for_all_epochs)
print(MAE_for_all_epochs)
print(MSE_for_all_epochs)

model_mae= MSE_for_all_epochs / epoch
model_mse= MAE_for_all_epochs / epoch
print("Model MAE: %f" % model_mae)
print("Model MSE: %f" % model_mse)
```

Model output this:

```
tensor(1445.2251)
1602.6452224985646
Model MAE: 534.215074
Model MSE: 481.741699
```

Comment: Why are you calling np.MSE_for_all_epochs?  Remove the np. part

Comment: I would like to convert them into NumPy. Is this not required?

Comment: MSE_for_all_epochs is a list. When you write np.something, that something must be a numpy function/method. MSE_for_all_epochs is something you defined yourself. To convert it into a numpy array, you need to write something like np.array(MSE_for_all_epochs).

Comment: Thanks very much, removing the np executed the model fully and got the value i need. Thanks

Comment: Sorry speaking too soon it seems there is something not correct with the calculations. The model print output the total then suppose to divide by 4(number of epoch) If i work out this isn't correct. Also, the first number is printed as tensor total and the second as NumPy. Any idea why would this be the case. Here's the output tensor(1445.2251)
1602.6452224985646
Model MAE: 534.215074
Model MSE: 481.741699

Comment: Without looking at your entire code it's hard to say what's happening where. Here's some guidelines you should follow though: If you have 1-d tensors to append to a list, you should call .item to append them. For example, `MAE_for_all_epochs.append(mean_test_error.item())` and `MSE_for_all_epochs.append(mse.item())`. This gives you a list of numbers, instead of a list of tensors.

Comment: If add ..item() i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train3_Eval.py", line 164, in <module>
    MSE_for_all_epochs.append(mse.item())
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: Then you don't need item, it is already a float. .item is used to convert tensors to floats, like (tensor(0.1)).item() = 0.1

Comment: Thanks! The number of epochs where i divide the code at the bottom seems to be one less from what i specified at the top. Is the easiest way to add 1 to the epoch. model_mae= MSE_for_all_epochs / epoch + 1